# Can someone see on Google meet if I muted them?

Tags: google-meet

If I mute someone on Google meet does it show that I muted them or it shows that someone has muted them and no name?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can see that you did it. There is a pop-up in the bottom.

From a tech site:

- Anyone in a Google Meet conference can mute anyone else.
- If you mute someone, no one in the conference will be able to hear them.
- When you mute someone, everyone will be notified that you have muted the person.
- You cannot unmute someone once they have been muted. They have to unmute themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can see that you did it. There is a pop-up in the bottom.

From a tech site:

Anyone in a Google Meet conference can mute anyone else.
If you mute someone, no one in the conference will be able to hear them.
When you mute someone, everyone will be notified that you have muted the person.
You cannot unmute someone once they have been muted. They have to unmute themselves.